# using a 4 wire cable to relocate light switch

Tags: switch

Is it NEC to use a 4 wire cable (black, red, white, ground) for a light switch?

The hot is wired to the panel (black) and red to the live. No need of a second wire...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is the more recent code to have a neutral(white) at the switch box, capped if not using it for a smart switch.

It is called a three wire cable with a silent ground, ground is usually not counted.

Older code allowed just a /2 cable from the light(power) and used the white as hot, and black as switched hot. A switch loop.

Comment: Yes, there will be a neutral connected to the switch. So I am concluding that it is allowed to use a 3 wires to run a switch?

Comment: Most smart switches require neutral at the box which is why the code was changed.  Old switch loops do not have neutral, only a hot white, so people who want smart switches have a hard time, sometimes needing to rewire.  Regular/dumb switches do not use neutral.  A new circuit to a switch box must contain neutral(/3 cable) to be in code.